# Solving hyperbolic system of pde using matlab

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, matlab, hyperbolic-equations

As part of my MPhil research work am to solve the system of nonlinear PDEs below using matlab. It's my first time working with matlab and I am finding it difficult generating the code to solve the problem. I will be very glad if anyone can help me. The initial conditions are
\begin{equation}
(u_0,T_0,\rho_0,p_0)=(80m/s,290K,0.83kg/m^3,2001.23Pa)
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix}
\rho\\
\rho u\\
\epsilon \rho
\end{pmatrix}_t
+
\begin{pmatrix}
\rho u\\
\rho u^2+p\\
(\epsilon \rho +p)u
\end{pmatrix}_x
-
\begin{pmatrix}
0\\
\rho g \sin(\theta)\\
\rho gu \sin(\theta)
\end{pmatrix}
=\begin{pmatrix}
0\\
0\\
\frac{4h}{D}(3003-T)
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
where 
$p=\frac{\rho RT}{1-\rho b}-a\rho^2$ and $\epsilon=c_vT-a\rho+\frac{u^2}{2}$
other constants are 
\begin{equation}
a=0.23, b=0.000043, h=100, D=0.5, g=10m/s^2,\theta=30^o, c_v=2.23, R=8.3145 
\end{equation}

Comment: Use for example "ode45" and modify an example using it... I don't think there is a better way if your lecturer hasn't shown you examples...

Answer (score 1):

This is a 1D hyperbolic system of partial differential equations with relaxation
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \boldsymbol{U} + \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \boldsymbol{F}(\boldsymbol{U}) = \boldsymbol{R}(\boldsymbol{U}) \, ,
$$
with unknowns $\boldsymbol{U} = (\rho,\rho u,\epsilon \rho)^\top$, physical flux $\boldsymbol{F}(\boldsymbol{U}) = (\rho u,\rho u^2 + p,(\epsilon \rho + p)u)^\top$, and relaxation function $\boldsymbol{R}(\boldsymbol{U}) = (0, \rho g \sin\theta , \rho g u\sin\theta + \frac{4h}{D}(3003-T))^\top$. For this kind of problem, a convenient strategy is *splitting*, which results in a propagation part
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \boldsymbol{U} + \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \boldsymbol{F}(\boldsymbol{U}) = \boldsymbol{0}
$$
and a relaxation part
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \boldsymbol{U} = \boldsymbol{R}(\boldsymbol{U}) \, .
$$
Numerically, both parts can be solved successively at each time step -- e.g. perform [Strang splitting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strang_splitting) -- with a dedicated numerical method. For instance, the propagation part is solved using the [Lax-Friedrichs scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lax%E2%80%93Friedrichs_method), and the relaxation part is solved using the backward [Euler method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_method).